# $\sum_{A\in2^\Omega}P(A)=2^{|\Omega|-1}$ for probability space $(\Omega,2^\Omega,P)$ with finite $\Omega$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinatorial-proofs

I'm looking for a combinatorial argument to complete a proof (below) of the following:

**Claim**: If $(\Omega,2^\Omega,P)$ is a probability space with finite $\Omega,$ then $\sum_{A\in2^\Omega}P(A)=2^{|\Omega|-1}.$

In other words, if $\Omega$ is finite and every subset of $\Omega$ is considered an event, then the sum of all the event-probabilities must equal $2^{|\Omega|-1}.$

Proof:
Let $\Omega=\{\omega_1,...,\omega_n\}$ and $p_i=P(\{\omega_i\}).$ Then, by summing over subsets of successively larger size,
$$\begin{align*}&\sum_{A\in\cal 2^\Omega}P(A)\\
&=P(\emptyset)+\sum_{1\le i_1\le n}P\{\omega_{i_1}\}+\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2\le n}P(\{\omega_{i_1},\omega_{i_2}\})+...+\sum_{1\le i_1<...<i_t\le n}P(\{\omega_{i_1},...,\omega_{i_t}\})+...+P(\Omega)\\[3ex]
&=\sum_{1\le i_1\le n}p_{i_1}+\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2\le n}(p_{i_1}+p_{i_2})+...+\sum_{1\le i_1<...<i_t\le n}(p_{i_1}+...+p_{i_t})+...+P(\Omega)\\[3ex]
&\overset{(*)}{=}\binom{n-1}{1-1}+\binom{n-1}{2-1}+...+\binom{n-1}{t-1}+...+\binom{n-1}{n-1}\\[3ex]
&=2^{n-1}
\end{align*}$$

The step marked $\overset{(*)}{=}$ would be justified by showing that in every sum $\sum_{1\le i_1<...<i_t\le n}(p_{i_1}+...+p_{i_t}),$ for $t=1,...,n,$ each of the $p_i (i=1,...,n)$ appears exactly $\binom{n-1}{t-1}$ times (noting of course that the sum of the $p_i (i=1,...,n)$ is $1$).

For example, if $n=4$ then for $t=2$ we have

$\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2\le 4}(p_{i_1}+p_{i_2})=(p_1+p_2)+(p_1+p_3)+(p_1+p_4)+(p_2+p_3)+(p_2+p_4)+(p_3+p_4)=3,$

as we see that each $p_i$ appears $\binom{4-1}{2-1}=3$ times.

Can anyone provide insight as to why this is generally the case? (Or perhaps give an alternative method of proof?)

---

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, the accepted answer provides a method that proves the following much more general result:

> If $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is a probability space with finite $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F$, then $\sum_{A\in\mathcal F}P(A)={1\over 2}|\mathcal F|.$

I.e., "the sum of all the event-probabilities must equal half the number of events".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's simpler to use that $P(A) + P(\overline A) = 1$. Note that $2^\Omega = \{A | A \subseteq \Omega\} = \{\overline A | A \subseteq \Omega\}$. So, we have

$$2 \cdot \sum_{A \in 2^\Omega} P(A) = \sum_{A \in 2^\Omega} P(A) + \sum_{A \in 2^\Omega} P(\overline A) = \sum_{A \in 2^\Omega} P(A) + P(\overline A) = \sum_{A \in 2^\Omega} 1 = 2^{|\Omega|}$$

Comment: Very neat! If I'm not mistaken, we can do similarly even when the event-field $\cal F\ne 2^\Omega$; viz., $\mathcal F=\{A|A\in\mathcal F\}=\{\overline A|A\in\mathcal F\},$ so $2 \cdot \sum_{A \in \mathcal F} P(A) = \sum_{A \in \mathcal F} P(A) + \sum_{A \in \mathcal F} P(\overline A) = \sum_{A \in \mathcal F} 1 = |\mathcal F|.$ And I notice that the title claim  still holds when $\Omega$ is not finite, as "half of infinity is infinity". In other words, the claim holds for all probability spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$!?

Comment: @r.e.s.  What is the definition of a sum of more than a countably infinite set of real numbers?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I should have been more careful, as I'm not sure there's a reasonable definition that allows the kind of statement I was making. Putting the infinite case aside, is it correct that the claim holds for all finite probability spaces, for any field of events?

Comment: It holds for any finite space, but that's not interesting, as any finite space can be factored by relation "two points are equal if any event containing one contains the other".

Comment: @DilipSarwate Still I wonder what can be said when the sigma-field is countably infinite; i.e., in that case are there really no conditions that would ensure a well-defined sum?

Comment: @WilliamM. it probably should be said that either sum over $K$ can be made small, or sum over any superset of $F$ is close to $x$, otherwise, for example, any partial sum of convergent series would be also it's sum...

Comment: @mihaild there were at least a couple of mistakes, so too bad. It is the utmost unfortunate that one cannot see the result of mathjax in the comments. Just sad.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof by switching the order of summation. First, write
$$
\sum_{A\subseteq\Omega } P(A)
=\sum_{A\subseteq \Omega}\sum_{\omega\in A}P(\omega)
$$
We can think of $\sum_{A\subseteq \Omega}\sum_{\omega\in A}P(\omega)$ as the sum of $P(\omega)$ over all ordered pairs $(\omega, A)$ such that $\omega\in A$. Switching the order of summation, we think of this as $\sum_{\omega\in \Omega}\sum_{A\ni \omega}P(\omega)$, where the inner summation ranges over all events $A$ which contain $\omega$. Since the summand $P(\omega)$ in the inner sum does depend on the summation index $A$, you can pull it out, resulting in
$$
\sum_{A\subseteq \Omega}P(\omega)\sum_{A\ni\omega}1
$$
To compute this inner summation, you just need to count the number of events containing $\omega$. This number is obviously $2^{n-1}$, and the rest is easy.